# Defining a delete(student st[], int *itemcount) function to delete a target record from the array of student objects

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

I'm trying to learn C programming so i was trying to do some practices. as you see below the search function only returns 1 or -1 and the variable index is being used to determine whether the target student exists or not. but after that it is again being used to determine whether it is the last, in the middle, or the first item in the array. how can index have that numeric value when we already assigned the returned value from the search function to it? please help me figure this out. thank you.

```
//function to delete record
void
delete_rec (student st[], int *itemcount) {
    char id[10];
    int index, i;
    if (*itemcount > 0) {
        printf ("Enter student's ID:");
        scanf ("%s", id);
        index = search (st, id, *itemcount);

        if ((index != -1) && (*itemcount != 0)) {
            if (index == (*itemcount - 1))  //delete the last record
            {

                clean (st, index);
                --(*itemcount);

                printf ("The record was deleted.\n");
            } else      //delete the first or middle record
            {
                for (i = index; i < *itemcount - 1; i++) {
                    st[i] = st[i + 1];
                    clean (st, *itemcount);
                    --(*itemcount);
                }

            }

        } else
            printf ("The record doesn't exist.Check the ID and try again.\n");


    } else
        printf ("No record to delete\n");
}

//function to clean deleted record
void
clean (student st[], int index) {

    strcpy (st[index].stnumber, "");
    strcpy (st[index].stname, "");
    st[index].sex = NULL;
    st[index].quizz1 = 0;
    st[index].quizz2 = 0;
    st[index].assigment = 0;
    st[index].midterm = 0;
    st[index].final = 0;
    st[index].total = 0;

}
```

Comment: `clean (st, *itemcount); --(*itemcount);` : wrong. and `&& (*itemcount != 0)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
how can index have that numeric value when we already assigned 
the returned value from the search function to it?
```

`index` (the value returned from `search()`) is set in search to **the actual loop index** for the record where the string comparison between `st[i].stnumber` and `id` match:

```
if (strcmp (st[i].stnumber, id) == 0)
    found = i;
. . .
return found;
```

That insures that `index` has the numeric value of the `index` for the record in your list. The return from `search()` is not `1` or `-1`.

Comment: When posting to StackOverflow, make sure you include the actual code you have questions about, **not** a link. Very few here will do what I did and go get the code for you. Look at the posting requirements, they are here for a reason. Good luck.